# Text in a frame - addParagraph options does not work - ReporteRs

Tags: r, reporters

I have a question. I want to add text to my slides. However I'd like to put my text within a frame.

I looked at the documentation - addParagraph function has argument par.properties but there is a short description:

`parProperties to apply to paragraphs. Shading and border settings will have no effect.`

[image]

Does it mean that I could not prepare the same text frame like as in an example above, using border and shading color? I checked that it is possible in wordx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, when using `ReporteRs`, you could prepare a master that has a shape behind your paragraph:

```
download.file("https://www.dropbox.com/s/0n7ili3fyfrgqgj/border_chart_templ.pptx?dl=1", tf_templ <- tempfile(fileext = ".pptx"), mode = "wb")
library(ReporteRs)
mydoc <- pptx( title = "title" , template = tf_templ)

mydoc <- addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "custom" )
mydoc <- addTitle( mydoc, "Border and background demo")
mydoc <- addParagraph( mydoc, value = "My text")

mydoc <- addSlide( mydoc, slide.layout = "chart" )
mydoc <- addTitle( mydoc, "Border and background demo with chart")
mydoc <- addParagraph( mydoc, value = "My text")
mydoc = addPlot( mydoc, function() barplot( 1:8, col = 1:8 ) )

writeDoc( mydoc, file = tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".pptx"))
shell.exec(tf)
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks, But I think it is not a solution when I want to prepare a slide with plot (on the left) and text frame (on the right). I mean I know that it is a matter of `slide.layout` and my template but this workaround is inconvenient a bit!

Comment: You'd prepare a master with a chart on the left and the paragraph on the right - I don't see any problem (and I use it myself, too :) ). However, I'm also open to other suggestions. Using `RDCOMClient` would IMHO be even more inconvenient.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but I asked about more customizable option in general. E.g. when I want to prepare a slide with plot on the top and text frame on the bottom. I know that I can create another template slides but IMHO it is inconvenient. It would be much easier to 'activate' `shading.color` and `border` arguments in pptx. But anyway, thanks for your concern:)

Comment: I had an idea to change default settings of text frame or shape within Powerpoint to customize it to my need, but unfortunately, it does not work when I use ReporteRs.

Comment: Nope. I got used to this approach when PowerPoint'ing from R. If you try out `RDCOMClient`, let me know how it worked out.